# Are my LED lights delayed because of a middle-strip connection?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I went to swap out a switch for a dimmer switch (Lutron, works with LED) in a one-way 3-gang setup.  I noticed they used the method where they strip out a section of a hot wire before looping it around a screw.  I believe the other 2 switches are on that same wire.  It took me a while to figure out with google what they did.  I went ahead and put the dimmer in.

Would them doing that wiring method be a cause for why my 4 new GE LED vanity lights (2 bulbs on each fixture) controlled by a DIFFERENT NON-DIMMER ON/OFF SWITCH IN THE SAME GANG, to experience a 4-5 second delay?  OR would that only be due to adding the dimmer switch and have nothing to do with how they wired?

The delay on the 4 vanity bulbs only occurs with the dimmer switch into the ON position.  In most cases, one bulb on each vanity will come on followed by the other 2.

The house was built in 2005.

UPDATE:
I am now seeing instances of the vanity lights (GE LED Edison-style bulbs) not coming on at all with the dimmer switch on.  It’s funny, if I slide the dimmer down, the vanity lights come on.

Comment: As long as good contact is provided, it should not matter.  Said dimmer works with LEDs, but do your LEDs work with dimmers?

Comment: @crip659 The dimmer controls a different single LED bulb (correctly).  The 4 vanity LED bulbs that are delayed are controlled by a non-dimmer switch in the same gang.

Comment: Dimmer should not be be the problem then.  Does it happen if the dimmer light is on or off?  LEDs can be sensitive to changing power, but usually causes flickers, not a delay.

Comment: @crip659  The delay on the 4 vanity bulbs only occurs with the dimmer switch into the ON position, so that’s why I was suspicious about how they wired the gang.  The delay is interesting too.  One bulb on each vanity will come on followed by the other 2.

Comment: Since you're comfortable opening up the switch box, turn the breaker off and pull all the switches out of the wall (do _NOT_ disconnect any wires). Get us some good pictures showing how everything is wired, indicate which switch controls what, and label which wire goes where. There may be something odd in the way you wired it back up that you're not seeing but that someone else will notice. (It's often hard to see what's wrong because you're seeing what you _expect_ to see, not what's _actually_ there - I do it all the time...)

Comment: @FreeMan - I may do that if I find the time.  I opened up to double check my work.  It is straightforward and operates correctly per the instructions.  I did not touch the other two switches.  It is very difficult to determine what wire is going where because most of them are coated in the same beige coloring.  I'm not sure if that was done via spray paint when they originally painted the walls or if the wires came that way.  One fact I have been withholding because I thought it would distract, is the vanity bulbs are GE low wattage edison-style bulbs.

Comment: If "the same beige coloring" is the color of "builder's beige" paint, then yeah, the painters were lazy and didn't cover the boxes well. You should be able to scrape the paint off by dragging a utility knife _backwards_ across the wire (don't use the normal cutting direction, you'll peel the insulation off and have to rewire). Don't withhold any facts - you never know which one will trigger someone's thought with the right answer.

Comment: It's going to be hard for us to help you diagnose this issue without those pics...

Comment: @FreeMan Understood.  I have 3 small children and it’s hard to find the right time to do that.  I’m most interested in, am I going to burn the house down?  It sounds to me like a hot wire is being shared by at least two of the switches and it’s not enough current (or voltage) for the edison bulbs.  If I swap out normal LED bulbs, I don’t have a delay.  I would wager if I replace the dimmer switch with a regular switch, the problem goes away.  I think it’s a combo of the transformer in the dimmer and a shared wire and edison bulbs.  But I don’t really understand it or KNOW.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is not uncommon, many LED dimmers cause the LEDs to delay turning on as they adjust their internal electronics etc. The brighter the setting the faster it will turn on. If you put your switch back it will go back to normal. Be sure the LEDs are dimmable. For testing if you can change one of the lamps to a tungsten filament one, it will work normally.

Comment: I tried to clarify what I mean in the original post.  The dimmer switch isn’t controlling the delayed LED’s, but is in the same gang.

Comment: If it is not the dimmer then something is not wired properly or a bad connection. Show your before and after pictures. Just for grins when the LEDs are on adjust the dimmer and tell what happens.

Comment: It does *seem* as though there is a difference with the slider all the way up vs all the way down, as to how easily the 4 vanity lights come on.  It’s almost as though because the 3 switches are sharing a wire (presumably) maybe there isn’t quite enough current to get to the 4 vanity bulbs (2 fixtures) quickly enough.  But I am not an electrician, so this is all guessing.

Comment: @DWPatt That sounds like the switch for the vanity lights is being slaved to the dimmer in some way. With a solid connection to power for the switch and the dimmer, the dimmer should not affect the switch, at all. This isn't a "middle strip" issue, it's either a loose connection or wrong connection issue.

Comment: @Ecnerwal This is the kind of opinion I am looking for, thank you.  I have been very hesitant to mess with something like this that I don’t understand 100%.  Our waterlines had to be redone recently after discovering negligence from the builder.  I know electrical isn’t plumbing, but I am assuming the worst to be on the safe side.